# excluding FALSE elements from a character vector by using logical vector

Tags: r

I manage to do the following:

```
stuff <- c("banana_fruit","apple_fruit","coin","key","crap")
fruits <- stuff[stuff %in% grep("fruit",stuff,value=TRUE)]
```

but I can't get select the-not-so-healthy stuff with the usual thoughts and ideas like

```
no_fruit <- stuff[stuff  %not in% grep("fruit",stuff,value=TRUE)]
#or
no_fruit <- stuff[-c(stuff  %in% grep("fruit",stuff,value=TRUE))]
```

don't work. The latter just ignores the "-"

Comment: You might want to put this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dave: This question is not statistics related.

Comment: It was tagged as "R" and a lot of questions relating to R are answered there I've noticed, but perhaps not ones relating exclusively to syntax as here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> stuff[grep("fruit",stuff)]
[1] "banana_fruit" "apple_fruit" 
> stuff[-grep("fruit",stuff)]
[1] "coin" "key"  "crap"
```

You can only use negative subscripts with numeric/integer vectors, not logical because:

```
> -TRUE
[1] -1
```

If you want to negate a logical vector, use `!`:

```
> !TRUE
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: ok, I see. I think I need the %in% syntax though in order to get logical values that would work with subset maybe. Is there a way to invert a logical vector? meaning TRUE becomes FALSE and the other way around?

Comment: @ran: Use `!` to do that, or just use `grepl` instead.

Comment: just curious: is there a general way to do it? I mean outside grep or subset?

Comment: But `stuff[-grep("car",stuff)]` does not do what you expect.

Comment: @hadley: it does what it's documented to do and that's what I expect.  Also, I suspected it wasn't what the questioner wanted, which is why I suggested `grepl` (as you did by commenting on Richie's answer).

Comment: The problem is that `grep("car",stuff)` returns `integer(0)`

Comment: @hadley: I'm aware of what it returns.  As I said, that's what it's documented to return.  You may disagree with the design choice, but that doesn't make it a problem.

Comment: It's certainly not what most people expect - and it comes up fairly regularly on R-help, so it deserves a mention.

Answer (score 2):

As Joshua mentioned: you can't use `-` to negate your logical index; use `!` instead.

```
stuff[!(stuff %in% grep("fruit",stuff,value=TRUE))]
```

See also the `stringr` package for this kind of thing.

```
stuff[!str_detect(stuff, "fruit")]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a parameter called 'invert' in grep that does essentially what you're looking for:

```
> stuff <- c("banana_fruit","apple_fruit","coin","key","crap")
> fruits <- stuff[stuff %in% grep("fruit",stuff,value=TRUE)]
> fruits
[1] "banana_fruit" "apple_fruit" 
> grep("fruit", stuff, value = T)
[1] "banana_fruit" "apple_fruit" 
> grep("fruit", stuff, value = T, invert = T)
[1] "coin" "key"  "crap"
```